# How to show menu bar in macOS with keyboard shortcut

Tags: macos

I'm on an 11.5" Macbook Air, so screen real estate is important to me. I currently have the menu bar set to auto-hide, but I want to be able to show the menu bar with a keyboard shortcut. Any ideas out there to do this without hacking something together?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

System Prefs > Keyboard > Shortcuts > Keyboard
Move focus to the Menu Bar [default  <kbd>Ctrl ⌃</kbd>   <kbd>F2</kbd>  ]

If you wish, you can then navigate the menu with the arrow keys - but it will pop the menu bar into view; Esc to close it without further interaction.

Answer (score 13):

I recommend <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>/</kbd>. It's the keyboard shortcut for a menu bar search. So it reveals the menu bar like <kbd>Ctrl⌃</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> does, with the added benefit of putting your cursor in the search field so you can quickly type the command you want and hit enter.

Comment: This does not work for me anymore (MacOS Ventura) since Cmd + ? is now the Help-window and ? is exactly Shift+/. See my question https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/457469/access-menu-bar-search-via-keyboard-shortcut

Comment: Pretty cool and fast

Answer (score 4):

If the standard

<kbd>Ctrl⌃</kbd> + <kbd>F2</kbd>

does not work try

<kbd>Ctrl⌃</kbd> + <kbd>F2</kbd> + <kbd>FN</kbd>

Comment: I could not figure out how to get the buttons to display right.  Can anyone fill me in?

Comment: Just place the `kbd`-tags around every single key (I used five pairs of tags to edit your post). You can just click the `edit`-button to see how it's done.

Answer (score 2):

For me, MacOS had it set up with this shortcut

<kbd>⌃ Control</kbd>+<kbd>⇧ Shift</kbd>+ <kbd>F2</kbd>